# Simpy Resource : Get ID?

Tags: python, simpy

I have two airport runways as a Simpy Resource:

```
runway = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2) # two runways
```

This works all fine, but how can I access the runway id (1 or 2) so that I can have an output such as 'Plane #1 taking off from runway #1'?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t (officially).  Internally, the slots are just a list so you could in theory use the list index of the Request.

Alternatively, you might use `Store` and put two "Runway" objects into it.  These objects have (of course) an ID an can also carry additional information (whatever you can imagine).